# 'ListBucketsCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

using  "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.481.0", and keep getting the error at send line

```
      let S3_Config = {
          region: process.env.S3_REGION,
          credentials: {
            accessKeyId:  process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
      },
    };
    const s3_client = new S3Client(S3_Config);

    const s3_params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME , // required
      MaxKeys: 20,
    };

    const _command = new ListBucketsCommand(s3_params);
    const response = await s3_client.send(_command);
```

> Argument of type 'ListBucketsCommand' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceInputTypes,
> ServiceOutputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes,
> SmithyResolvedConfiguration>'.   Type
> 'ListBucketsCommand' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes,
> ServiceOutputTypes, SmithyResolvedConfiguration>':
> input, middlewareStack, resolveMiddlewarets(2345)

This is the exact example as shown https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3?activeTab=readme

Comment: What is the content of `s3_params`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After playing all different versions etc, finally the age old deleting the node_module and package.lock.json file and reinstalling worked.

My versions are as follows:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.363.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.485.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.363.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.431.0",
"@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.365.0",
"@aws-sdk/smithy-client": "^3.374.0",
"@smithy/types": "^2.5.0",
"@types/node": "^20.3.3",
```

Comment: Will vote to close the question as "Not reproducible", I guess.

Answer (score 0):

ListBucketsCommand in AWS SDK v3 doesn't require any input parameters, so pass an empty object {} when creating the command.

```
let S3_Config = {
  region: process.env.S3_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId:  process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
  },

};
const s3_client = new S3Client(S3_Config);

const s3_params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME , // required
    MaxKeys: 20,
};

const _command = new ListBucketsCommand({}); // No input params are needed for ListBucketsCommand
const response = await s3_client.send(_command);
```

Or you can try an alternate command that is present in the aws-sdk package that does the same thing

```
const { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.S3_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
  },
});

const s3Params = {
  Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
  MaxKeys: 20,
};

const listObjectsCommand = new ListObjectsV2Command(s3Params);

try {
  const response = await s3Client.send(listObjectsCommand);
  console.log(response.Contents);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: Still getting the error: 

Argument of type 'ListBucketsCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, SmithyResolvedConfiguration<HttpHandlerOptions>>'.
  Type 'ListBucketsCommand' is missing the following properties from type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, SmithyResolvedConfiguration<HttpHandlerOptions>>': input, middlewareStack, resolveMiddleware

Comment: What is the JavaScript/TypeScript version that you're using and have you checked its compatibility with the aws-sdk?

Comment: "typescript": "^5.1.6",     "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.484.0",

Comment: Is this the way that you imported the ListBucketsCommand: import { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

Comment: Also, can you try renaming the _command to command variable

Comment: yes, the import is as follows:

import { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

I dont think renaming command will make any difference, but i did it and still the same error.

Comment: I tried running the code of AnujPanchal and it ran successfully @RafatSarosh . As he stated, ListBucketsCommand takes an empty object as input. Also, try reinstalling the package and ensure you have the correct node version.

Comment: This Command signature `Command<ServiceInput....` looks like is not the correct for the pointed AWS SDK version. It's possible that you have some @smithy/types dependency conflict. Try installing/forcing the dependency "@smithy/types": "2.5.0".

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Here are my libraries:

    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.485.0",
    "@aws-sdk/smithy-client": "^3.374.0",
    "@smithy/types": "^2.8.0",
    Node: v20.10.0
    tsc: 5.1.6
    
    const input = {};
    const _command = new ListBucketsCommand(input);
    const response = await s3_client.send(_command);  //ERROR!!

Still getting Error :  Argument of type 'ListBucketsCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, SmithyResolvedConfiguration<HttpHandlerOptions>>

Comment: @RafatSarosh, I have added another alternate piece of code in my answer mentioned above. I tried and it is working. Maybe you can try that too.

Comment: Anuj can you please share your lib versions:


"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.485.0", 
"@aws-sdk/smithy-client": "^3.374.0", 
"@smithy/types": "^2.8.0", 
"Node": v20.10.0 
"tsc": 5.1.6

Comment: I have used just "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "v3.485.0". That's it

Comment: Can you create a little public GitHub Repo reproducing the error? So we can download and verify.